# Xamarin Android FrameLayout and Content Overlapping on Navigation Bar And on Menu

Tags: android, xamarin

[Screenshot 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxn7UXgmstmRQ3ZJM0psajJ2YUU)

[Screenshot 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxn7UXgmstmRSzNRVXBldE56cGc)

The above screen shots is preview for application previewing on android. As you see the FrameLayout and content of FrameLayout is overlapping on NavigationBar and on Menu. How should I make the content visible within frame. Also I want the content should placed behind the NavigationBar.

**Below is the code of Main.axml file:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
           />

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/nav_view"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
      app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
     />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I make the content visible within frame. Also I want the content should placed behind the NavigationBar.

Put your `FrameLayout` and `toolbar` in a `LinearLayout` like this :

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ll">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/framelayout"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
         />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT :**

> no content is visible on menu item click

In your `toolbar.axml`, your `CoordinatorLayout`'s `layout_height` property is `match_parent`, so no content is visible.

Modify your `toolbar.axml` code like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/main_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/appbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:elevation="4dp"
       android:background="#2196F3" />
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then your project will works fine.